# Script broken after moving it to another gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I had a script that controlled my main menu that was on a GameObject and moved it to another gameobject and reconnected all the loose ends. now for some reason none of my buttons work, even with highlighting.

just had two gameobjects and moved the script between them using the editor
the script itself doesnt do much, just this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject mainMenu;
    public GameObject optionsMenu;
    public GameObject modeMenu;
    public Dropdown resolutionDropdown;
    private Resolution[] resolutions;
    public Toggle fullscreenToggle;

    public void StartGameLocal()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Local2P");
    }

    public void StartGameAI()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("AI2P");
    }

    public void MenuToOptions()
    {
        mainMenu.SetActive(false);
        optionsMenu.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void OptionsToMenu()
    {
        mainMenu.SetActive(true);
        optionsMenu.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void MenuToMode()
    {
        mainMenu.SetActive(false);
        modeMenu.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void ModeToMenu()
    {
        mainMenu.SetActive(true);
        modeMenu.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void ExitGame()
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        resolutions = Screen.resolutions;
        resolutionDropdown.ClearOptions();
        List<string> options = new List<string>();
        int currentResolutionIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < resolutions.Length; i++)
        {
            string option = resolutions[i].width + " x " + resolutions[i].height;
            options.Add(option);
            if (resolutions[i].width == Screen.width && resolutions[i].height == Screen.height)
                currentResolutionIndex = i;
        }
        resolutionDropdown.AddOptions(options);
        resolutionDropdown.value = currentResolutionIndex;
        resolutionDropdown.RefreshShownValue();
        if (Screen.fullScreen == true)
        {
            fullscreenToggle.isOn = true;
        }
    }

    public void SetResolution(int resolutionIndex)
    {
        Resolution resolution = resolutions[resolutionIndex];
        Screen.SetResolution(resolution.width,
                  resolution.height, Screen.fullScreen);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("ResolutionPreference", resolutionDropdown.value);
    }

    public void SetFullscreen(bool isFullscreen)
    {
        Screen.fullScreen = isFullscreen;
        if (isFullscreen)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("FullscreenPreference", 1);
        }
        else
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("FullscreenPreference", 0);
        }
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (optionsMenu.activeSelf)
            {
                OptionsToMenu();
            }
            else if (optionsMenu.activeSelf)
            {
                ModeToMenu();
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Quit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i dont know how to fix this and why my buttons just stopped working, even after reconnecting everything, but please help!
p.s. havent checked the update code to see if it worked, if yall have suggestions let me know

Comment: Are you sure you have assign new object to your buttons on unity editor ?

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons likely pointed to the functions in this script in their OnClick handlers.  If you moved the location of the script, you need to go to each of the buttons and hook those handlers back up.